# second level recycle bin O365 Education license

Tags: office-365, recycle-bin

I had this event happening to me. 2 different sites collections. One item has been deleted from one and it went straight to the second level recycle bin. The other site collection correctly placed it in the first recycle bin.

Is there a setting that controls how much time an item stays in the first level recycle bin? Also, I have read on blogs that an item stays in the second level bin for 93 days, is this correct?

Comment: Does anyone know why 93 days was chosen?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, 93 days in total is how long a file will be around when it is deleted. This is not configurable in SharePoint Online.

If the user who deletes the file, deletes it from the first stage recycle bin, it will move to the second stage bin until the 93 days in total has been hit. Did the user who deleted the file from the library delete it from the first stage as well?

If you can reproduce this in a specific site collection and not others, open a case with Microsoft Support through your Office 365 Admin center.

Comment: my understanding was that the user did not have enough knowledge to delete it from the first bin